# Select the Max date time for single User

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this,

```
Date    User
15-06-2018  A
16-06-2018  A
15-06-2018  B
14-06-2018  C
16-06-2018  C
```

I want to get the output like this,

```
Date    User
16-06-2018  A
15-06-2018  B
16-06-2018  C
```

I tried `Select  Max(date),User from Table group by User`

Comment: Your query looks fine.  What error are you having?

Comment: I have 80 columns in select list

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question -- what error are you having?  I took a guess at your issue below, but sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: If you have 80 columns then that is a poor example of desired output.

Comment: What is your question????  You provide input, output, query attempt, but no question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, I assume you have duplicated results in those 80 columns when you `group by` them.  Assuming so, here's one option using `row_number` to always return 1 row per user:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by user order by date desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *correlation* `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where date = (select max(t1.date) 
              from table t1 
              where t1.user = t.user
             );
```

However, i would also recommend `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by user order by date desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a ranking function

```
SELECT User, Date
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT User, Date
           , Row_id = Row_Number() OVER (Partition by User,  ORDER BY User, Date desc)
        FROM table
    )q
WHERE Row_Id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this

```
Select * from table t where exist 
 (Select 1 from 
  (Select user, max(date) as date from table) A
    Where A.user = t.user and A.date = t.date )
```